# GSuite Permissions on Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-workspace

#### Initial Question

I'm trying to do something that I think is somewhat simple, but I can't seem to get it nailed down correctly. I've been trying to create a bucket on GCS that is accessible to anyone in my GSuite organization, but not the larger internet.

I've created an org@mydomain.com group and added all users. I then granted that user permission to view the file in the bucket, but it always says access denied. If the file is marked public then it's accessible without issue. How do I get this setup?

#### Additional Information

1. I have transferred the project and bucket to my organization
2. I have setup the index and 404 pages
3. If marked public, everything works as expected
4. When I check the permissions of individual files, I don't see anything inherited or more specific than the general project security settings.
5. I added the Storage Object Viewer permission to the bucket for my org@domain.com group

When trying to access a file, I get the following response:

```
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access denied.</Message>
    <Details>
        Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to compliance.microcimaging.com/test_xray.jpg.
    </Details>
</Error>
```

So, thinking that it might be thinking I was using a different account, I opened an Incognito Window, logged in as my organization, then attempted to access. That gave me the same message.

I tried adding the org@domain.com user to a single file, which resulted in the same error. I then attempted to add my personal username to the file, which resulted in the same error.

Permission errors have got to be the **MOST BORING** errors!

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that you already created a Google group you can accomplish this quite easily.

On Google Cloud Platform Console go to "Storage -> Browser", and on your bucket, on the menu on the right select "edit bucket permissions".

On "Add members" put org@mydomain.com and give the role of "Storage -> Storage Object Viewer" to give the whole group read only permissions when authenticated or any other permission combination you need.

Alternatively see [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview#g_suite_domain) about how to set IAM policies on a Gsuite domain, so you can even skip the group part and set access control policies to the Google Cloud products for your domain as a whole.

Comment: Jordi, I thought that was the process and I have that setup, but I still can't access. I filled in more details above.

Comment: Hi, that'sd weird, I just tested it and worked for me. Make sure you have the following things correctly configured:
  
- The email you used to grant the role on the IAM control panel is the correct group email. That's the group address and should look like "name-of-the-group@yourorganization.com" . You can get it by going to the group page and selecting "about".
  
- The users have accepted the invitation to join the group. Otherwise they will get a 403 error (forbidden, as their email is not part of the group so it doesn't inherit any permissions)
  
Once those

Comment: Jordi, thank you for all your help, but this still doesn't want to work for me. One of the oddest things is that if I go to one of the files, I can see my domain account as the "Owner" of the file, but I still can't access it. Is there another setting I'm missing?

Comment: Hi, are you authenticated?  What error are you getting? I can't think of any reason where the owner of the file wouldn't be able to access it