# Google cloud storage bucket not accessible by workspace domain users

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-iam

I am trying to create a csv file on google cloud storage bucket using python webapp2 using below code :

```
 full_filename = '/' + TEST_BUCKET + "/" + DATA + "/" + 'employee.csv'
    logging.info("full_filename is %s ", full_filename)
    gcs_file = cloudstorage.open(full_filename,
                                 'w',
                                 content_type='text/plain',
                                 retry_params=cloudstorage.RetryParams(backoff_factor=1.1))
    gcs_file.write(file_obj.getvalue())
    gcs_file.close()
    logging.info("done writing into cloud storage !!")
```

It's getting created successfully , and Developers who are part of GAE console can see the content of the file.

But employees who are not part of `GAE` console can't see this and getting `403 Forbidden`.

The idea is that employee's who are part of the same org(let's take google workspace domain as : example.com) should be able to access this file irrespective of they are part of GAE console or not.
So for that I tried giving bucket level permissions(`uniform access control`) and added example.com as new principals and Role as :  `Storage Legacy Bucket Reader` But they are still getting same `403 Forbidden`.

Resources:
https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview#g_suite_domain

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control

[GSuite Permissions on Google Cloud Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48706088/gsuite-permissions-on-google-cloud-storage)

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists

Comment: Being a member of Workspace does not automatically grant permissions to Cloud Storage. How is your code adding authorization to API calls? Your question does not show those details.

Answer (score 0):

This error (403) indicates that the user was not authorized by Google Cloud Storage to make the request.

- The various possible causes for this error are listed in the Google Cloud Storage error [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-status#403%E2%80%94forbidden) for 403-Forbidden.
- A common source of this error is that the bucket permissions (bucket ACL) are not set properly to allow your app access.

Since you mentioned that the Developers who are a part of GAE are able to access the bucket contents, so we can rule out the ACL scenario as mentioned above.

However, you may try out the following:

- Add the domain users to a Group.
- On Google Cloud Platform Console go to "Storage -> Browser", and on your bucket, on the menu on the right select "edit bucket permissions".
- On "Add members" put the Group and give the role of "Storage -> Storage Object Viewer" to give the whole group read only permissions when authenticated or any other permission combination you need.

Alternatively, you may have a look at this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview#g_suite_domain) for more details.

Comment: I have posted an answer. Can you check if that helps?